# Where in build.gradle can I define the app name?

Tags: android, gradle

It may be a very simple question but I cannot find how to specify an app name in build.gradle  in the format 'com.company.app'. Below is the documentation I am trying to follow.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set-application-id) contains the following example for how to set this “app name” (or “package name” or “application ID”):

```groovy
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ...
}
```

Here, `com.example.myapp` is the “app name”. The documentation also contains more details on the rules for such names and other recommendations for choosing a good name.

Answer (score 0):

i have been having this issue, although by looking at this [doc](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-you-want-change-app-name-based-build-type-support-elnaggar) i could figure something out

maybe by using `manifestPlaceholders = [appName:"app name"]` and specifying it in buildtypes

```
buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         manifestPlaceholders = [appName:"app name"]
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, The App Package name(`com.companyname.projectName`) and app name (`app name`) are different things. The App Package name should be unique but the app name is duplicated with a different app package name.

We can set both the things in `app/build.gradle` file. Like blow:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    debug{
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App Name"
       ...
    }
    release {
        resValue "string", "app_name", "App Name"
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, You can use `app_name` string in your app manifest file. Alow, This helps you to set different app names for debug and release app. like below:

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
```

I hope this will help you to solve your prblem.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the app name in string.xml file

`<string name="app_name">AppName</string>`

Or You may change in Manifest file

```
 <application
    android:label="@string/app_name or you may add static Name here">
```

OR You may change in settings.gradle file

```
rootProject.name = “New Project Name”
```